# Динамическая подгрузка при прокрутке экрана

Tags: android, listview, прокрутка

Привет всем!!!

Мое приложение умеет загружать данные с сервера и выводить их списком на экран.

Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы данные выводились при прокрутке экрана, а не сразу всей кучей.

Как это сделать?

Очень хочется увидеть пример, в котором что-то грузиться с инета и подгружается с прокрутом экрана.

Comment: где то видел статья по такой загрузке... если откопаю в избраном кину

Comment: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: dogmar, теги посмотри сначала прежде чем советы давать.

Answer (score 2):

Сам так не делал, но делал бы так:

1. Данные извлекать из базы не одним запросом, а по n штук в запросе.
2. При первом открытии страницы извлекаем первые n.
3. Проверяем при каждом скроллировании экрана, дошли ли до конца экрана или нет.
4. Если дошли, то подгружаем следующие n записей.

Answer (score 1):

На то существует понятие `CursorAdapter` - он сам автоматом будет "подсасывать" нужное количество записей. Почитайте мануалы, погуглите по примерам использования `CursorAdapter`

Comment: не поможет, мапить не начто будет, надр в фоне грузить контент и тд

Comment: Что значит "мапить не начто будет"?

Comment: курсорАдаптеру надр данные, а их не будет, потому что еще не загруженые

Comment: @Gorets ты плохо изучил тексты наших адаптеров :) - вкури еще раз как там все устроено и увидишь, что как раз так как хочет @Stas0n

Comment: @Barmaley здравствуйте! Подскажите как сделать "ленивую загрузку" списка ? Есть список, при старте приложения я качаю через API 10 JSON объектов, и заношу данные из них в базу SQLite, потом читаю данные из базы в ArrayList и этот ArrayList передаю адаптеру списка. ПРОБЛЕМА: как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь начал прокручивать список, к примеру прокрутил вниз на одну позицию - скачался еще один JSON объект, занесся в базу, из базы он вставился в конец списка? Спасибо.

Comment: @Andrew оформите вопрос как положено. В каментах вопрос - как то не айс

Comment: @Barmaley, хорошо. Сейчас кину ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: @Barmaley [вопрос] http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466662/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-rest-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-json-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9     Если у Вас есть советы и наставления как это грамотно сделать - пожалуйста ответьте)

Answer (score 1):

http://android-helper.com.ua/pull-to-refresh/

большой, но хороший пример

Comment: А какие методы там отвечают за то, что мне нужно?
Да и вообще - там же просто обновление листа, а не очередная его подгрузка...

Comment: скачай и поковыряй пример, так красиво можно реализовать подгрузку новых данных с нэта