# Как правильно организовать REST-клиент ? Асинхронная загрузка JSON, изображений в базу и отображении в списке

Tags: android, json, listview, api, rest

Хочу разобраться разобраться как правильно организовать REST-клиент.

Есть API, которая по запросу выдает JSON объекты.

Нужно построить список ListView(или лучше использовать RecyclerView?) из этих JSON.

Как я это все делаю:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String API = "https://api.github.com";

    ListView listView;
    UserAdapter adapter;
    DBHandler mDBhandler;


    int lastUserIDinList=0;
    //начальное кол-во пользователей в списке
    int initialAmountUsers=10;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBhandler = new DBHandler(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<GitHubUser>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new CountUserInDB().execute();

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                loadUsers(1);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    //получаем от API объекты, ждем коллбэк и запускаем AsyncTask запись в базу(в качестве параметра передаем список моделей)
    void loadUsers(int count){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder() .setEndpoint(API).build();
        GitAPI git = restAdapter.create(GitAPI.class);
        //полчаем от АПИ пользователей с ид больше lastUserIDinList. количество пользователей в ответе - count
        git.getNextUsers(lastUserIDinList, count, new Callback<ArrayList<GitHubUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<GitHubUser> gitHubUsers, Response response) {
                new WriteToDB().execute(gitHubUsers);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }



    //get arralist of users and write it to db
    class WriteToDB extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<GitHubUser>,Void,Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(ArrayList<GitHubUser>... params) {
            //заноси в таблицу всех пользователей полученных в коллбэке
            for(int i=0; i<params[0].size(); i++){
                mDBhandler.addUser(params[0].get(i));
            }
            //получаем ИД первой записи, чтобы с нее начать читать из базы
            return params[0].get(0).getId();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer firstID) {
            super.onPostExecute(firstID);
            //вызываем четние из базы с первого ид, который пришел в ответе от АПИ
            new ReadFromDB().execute(firstID);
        }
    }


    //get id of userd from what need to read from db
    class ReadFromDB extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,ArrayList<GitHubUser>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<GitHubUser> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            //читаем из базы всех пользователей, ид которых >= params[0]
            return mDBhandler.getUserFromID(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<GitHubUser> userList) {
            super.onPostExecute(userList);
            new DisplayUserInListView().execute(userList);
        }
    }




    //get arralist of users and add it to adapter
    class DisplayUserInListView extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<GitHubUser>,Void,Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<GitHubUser>... params) {
            //добавляем по очереди пользователей в адаптер
            for(int i=0; i<params[0].size(); i++){
                adapter.addItem(params[0].get(i));
                lastUserIDinList=params[0].get(i).getId();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //сообщаем, что обновили данные
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }




    class CountUserInDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        int lastUserIDinTable=-1;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //получаем ИД последней записи в таблице
            lastUserIDinTable=mDBhandler.getLastUseID();
            //получаем количество пользователей в таблице
            return mDBhandler.getUserCount();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer userCount) {
            super.onPostExecute(userCount);

            if(userCount==0){
                //база пуста, загрузим 10 пользователей для начала
                loadUsers(10);
            }

            if(userCount>=initialAmountUsers){
                //в базе больше 10 пользователей, что достаточно для начала - читаем из базы.
                new ReadFromDB().execute(0);
            }

            if(userCount>0 && userCount<initialAmountUsers){
                //в базе меньше 10 пользователей, но не 0.
                //грузим часть из базы, остальное догружаем из АПИ
                new ReadFromDB().execute(0);
                lastUserIDinList=lastUserIDinTable;
                loadUsers(initialAmountUsers-userCount);

            }

        }
    }





}
```

У меня такое чувство, что сделал какой-то велосипед.

Какие есть советы по улучшение(или переделыванию полностью) логики ?
Не много ли я использую AsyncTask ?

Интересны любые советы по грамотному получению JSON объектов, использованию API, добавлением итемов в список..

**UPD:**

Почитав статьи, пришел к выводу, что REST клиента на андроиде нужно делать по двум вариантам:

1)Создавать сервис, в котором будут загружаться данные с API(), парситься, записываться в базу и потом передавать в активити сообщение, что надо обновить список. Активити как получит такое уведомление, с помощью CursorLoader'а грузит данные из таблицы и добавляет их адаптеру списка.

2)Не создавать сервисов, а в активити с помощью AsyncTaskLoader'ов(для получения инфы в фоне, при этом еще использовать Retrofit) и CursorLoader'ов, с помощью которых читать/писать базу.

Какой из этих подходов более грамотный ? Возможно есть какие-то дополнения или уточнения к этим подходам ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Многократно уже отписывался на эту тему, как писать REST клиента. Не поленюсь написать еще раз:

1. Через сервис тягаем JSON объекты из сети и складываем в SQLite БД
2. Над SQLite БД создаем `ContentProvider` и через `CursorLoader` организуем подпитку `CursorAdapter`, который и будет адаптером для `ListView` или `RecyclerView`
3. Вопрос выбора `ListView` или `RecyclerView` - это вопрос не только вкуса, но и квалификации (все таки). Как показывает опыт `RecyclerView` сложнее в понимании, но дает гораздо большую свободы в плане управления списком. Я бы рекомендовал начинать с `ListView` и только потом приступать к `RecyclerView`
4. Для работы с JSon лучшим инструментом является [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) - берите его и даже не сомневайтесь. Функция Gson очень простая, но важная: это трансляция вашего Java объекта в Json строку и обратно. По сути вместо рутинного парсинга json строки вы будете иметь дело с интеллигентными Java классами.
5. Часто при работе с Rest требуется реализация функциональности *Pull-To-Refresh* - ну то есть обновление списка при *вытягивании* вверх/вниз. В сети есть огромное количество реализаций Pull-To-Refresh. Я пользовался [этим проектом](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) - но он сейчас мертвый. Недавно в суппорт либах появился [новый виджет](http://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html): `SwipeRefreshLayout` я лично не пользовался не знаю как с ним работать. Те из знакомых кто пользовались - пищат от восторга. У меня нет оснований не доверять им.

P.S. Для `RecyclerView` организовать `CursorAdapter` напрямую не получится, нужно будет применить [эту наработку](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59).

**Update**

```
Создавать сервис, в котором будут загружаться данные с API(), парситься, 
записываться в базу и потом передавать в активити сообщение, что надо 
обновить список. Активити как получит такое уведомление, с помощью 
CursorLoader'а грузит данные из таблицы и добавляет их адаптеру списка.
```

1. В качестве сервиса подойдет `IntentService`, который можно запускать по таймеру и/или через событие генерируемое при *Pull-To-Refresh*
2. Не надо никак уведомлять `Activity` о том, что БД изменилось - `CursorLoader` сам будет автоматом подгружать обновленные данные при изменении БД через соответствующий `Observer` (в случае `RecyclerView`), а в случае `CursorAdapter` это уже будет "из коробки"

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout действительно классная штука.

Comment: Несколько вопросов еще: 1.Через сервис ? Какой сервис Вы имеете ввиду ? 2.Как я понимаю, для загрузки из базы данных, вместо AsyncTask, как у меня, можно(или даже нужно?) использовать CursorLoader?  P.S. GSON использую вместе с Retrofit, спасибо!

Comment: Прочел Ваш ответ несколько раз, почитал интернет.. Обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы случаем не этот паттерн имеете ввиду: REST pattern A - представленный на Google i/o 2010  http://hsto.org/files/fab/18d/8fe/fab18d8fec7a43a39c5b5285720e6771.png

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не отметил как ответ. Спасибо! Вы ответили на мой вопрос!