# AsyncTask и поворот экрана

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Есть множество туториалов/статей как надо сохранять состояние AsyncTask при повороте экрана, но все же..

Есть одна activity, в ней есть много раз вызывается несколько разных AsyncTask'ов.

Как то так:

```
    void startTask(){
         new SomeAsyncTask1.execute();
         new SomeAsyncTask22.execute();
    }
```

Как лучше всего сохранять состояние AsyncTask'ов и чтобы после поворота экрана они спокойно закончили выполнение ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше используйте [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) - позволяет не задумываться о сохранении состояния. Если описывать вкратце и на пальцах, то этот класс выполнит запрос в фоне (под капотом там тот же самый асинктаск), и в коллбеке возвратит результат. Штука тут в том, что после смены ориентации экрана, лоадер спокойно завершит свою работу(если еще не завершил) и все равно возвратит результат в коллбеке, Вам же ничего самому писать не нужно.

Comment: А как будет в такой ситуации: я запустил AsyncTaskLoader, который при загрузке добавляет в ListView по очереди итем списка(данные приходят от АПИшки). Потом я делаю поворот(AsyncTaskLoader работает еще). И тут я вызываю еще раз AsyncTaskLoader, чтобы еще новые данные в список подгрузить. Данные не перемешаются ? Т.е. первый AsyncTaskLoader еще не закончил работу после поворота, но я уже запустил еще один AsyncTaskLoader и он закончил и добавил итем в список. Потом закончит первый Таск и тоже добавит итем = будет нарушен порядок. Или в AsyncTaskLoader предусмотрена какая-то очередь ?

Comment: если будете несколько раз вызывать Loader.forceload(), то запросы будут выполняться по очереди. А вообще рекомендую изучить документацию. В случае загрузки данных в Listview этот класс - то, что Вам нужно

Comment: спасибо! Сейчас буду разбираться!

Comment: Посмотрел несколько примеров, туториалов. Не могу понять как это может быть полезно в моей ситуации. Если Вам не трудно, поясните..

Comment: В этом [посте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466662/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-rest-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-json-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) есть мой код, там показано когда и сколько я использую AsyncTask'ов

Comment: В том посте в первом комменте человек замечательно описал, как нужно делать, подписываюсь под каждым словом. Кстати, он тоже советовал применять лоадеры. К сожалению обьяснять нужно долго, а времени нет. Если совсем не понятно, что делать, то сперва досконально изучите документацию, для всех терминов, упомянутых в том комменте - сразу станет яснее. Время потратите немало, но оно того стоит. Удачи!

Comment: Мне в целом понятно, что имел ввиду тот человек. И у меня так и работает, правда без лоадеров. У меня в асинктаске пишется в базу распарсенные GSON'ом данные, из базы данные грузятся в ListView.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно как работает AsyncTaskLoader. Как я понял: создавай в активити менджер лоадеров, когда нам надо запустить какой-то АсинкТаск, мы делаем это через этот менеджер. И при повороте экрана, этот менеджер как-то знает, что такие-то таки еще выполняются и нужно ждать от них ответа и если пользователь запускает еще таск, то оно становится в очередь за последним таском до поворота экрана.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" Вот такая вещь не подходит?
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Но категорически нет.. Использовать запрет это плохая практика..