# Как перенаправить на другую страницу с помощью jsoup и продолжать выводить содержание контента в ListView?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, listview

Есть сайт, где основное содержание это список постов с текстом. За каждый пост отвечает такой блок HTML кода.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em">Some text</div>
```

Чтобы распарсить посты и выводить их в ListView я реализовал такой AsyncTask.

```
class NewPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Новые");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); 

            content = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");
            titleList.clear();

            for (Element contents : content) {
                if (!contents.text().contains("18+")) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Но у меня есть одна проблема. Все сообщения хранятся не на одной странице. Внизу на странице после всех постов есть блок с номерами страниц и ссылками на них.
[image: Пример блока ссылок]

И за этот блок отвечает такой HTML код.

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="paginator">

                <span class="pagina">1683</span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1682">1682</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1681">1681</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1680">1680</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1679">1679</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/3">3</a></span> " | "

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/2">2</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1">1</a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как мне перейти на другую страницу, разобрать другие посты и вывести их в ListView после предыдущих постов? В результате я хочу иметь все посты этого сайта в одном ListView. Можете показать мне, как такое сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `url` ведет на главную страницу сайта (т.е. не содержит указания на страницу):

Сделайте метод, который принимает `Document` JSoup и вставляет нужные строки в `ListView` (то, что у вас уже сделано, `titleList.clear()` только в него не вставьте). Пусть будет `parseDocument(Document doc)`.

1. Получите `Document` для первой страницы
2. Обработайте страницу вызовом `parseDocument`
3. Получите номер страницы селектором типа `div.paginator > span:first-child`, преобразуйте в число (пусть будет `int pageCount`)
4. В цикле от `pageCount - 1` до `1` включительно создавайте ссылку на страницу, получите по ней `Document` и вызывайте `parseDocument`.

Может возникнуть проблема с появлением на следующих страницах строк из ранее обработанных страниц, при добавлении новых статей на сайт. Возможно, стоит проверять хвост списка на дубликаты.

Дополнение про получение номера страницы:

`element.toString()` возвращает элемент вместе с тегами, `element.text()` - содержимое внутри тегов. Чтобы получить номер страницы, сделайте:

```
// выбрать всех первых детей элемента div с классом paginator
Elements pageSpan = doc.select( "div.paginator > span:first-child" );
// взять текст из первого найденного элемента
int pageCount = Integer.parseInt( pageSpan.first().text() );
```

Стоит еще проверить, что элементы нашлись, вызовом `!pageSpan.isEmpty()`, так как `first()` для пустого списка возвращает `null`.

Comment: На 3 этапе появляется исключение java.lang.NumberFormatException:Invalid int: "<span class="pagina">1683</span>
                                                                   <span class="pagina">1683</span>"

Видимо не так нужно получать номер страницы?

Код:
String pageCountString = String.valueOf(doc.select("div.paginator > span:first-child"));
int pageCount = Integer.parseInt(pageCountString);

Comment: на [try.jsoup.org](http://try.jsoup.org) можете [попробовать](http://try.jsoup.org/~9Xjn2yV2nEIaIIOFZB0VKbHT6aE) разные селекторы

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и сайт! Добавьте это все в ответ и я отмечу его как решение :)

Comment: В общем, в моем решении есть недостаток - все посты загружаются за раз, что приводит к долгой загрузке и потери мегабайтов для пользователей. Есть какой-то способ загружать по 10 постов, а остальные загружать (парсить) только когда пользователь дойдет конца списка?

Comment: Ответ обновил. По поводу обновления, взрослые андроидщики рекомендуют [такую схему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466699/190934), только вместо json у вас будет результат работы JSoup. Если это сложно, то можно запомнить номер последней загруженной страницы в поле activity, сделать кнопку и по нажатию догружать следующую страницу. Но тут я могу вас плохому научить, я не настоящий android-разработчик.